# Unable to instantiate Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring, and have a simple problem.
I have written a simple controller with a simple constructor, annotated as shown below.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController
{
   private LoginService loginService;

   @Inject
   public LoginController(LoginService loginService)
   {
      System.out.println("LoginController constructor - initializing  login service");
      this.loginService = loginService;
   }
```

When I try to access my web app in a browser, I get the following error:
 No default constructor found;

When I replace the **@Inject** annotation with the **@Autowired** annotation, it works.  Can anyone explain why?  Everything I've read says that have identical behavior.  I'm using Tomcat 6.0.43.

Also, below is my spring dispatcher servlet xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    
<mvc:annotation-driven/>                                            

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rockwell_collins.webquery"/>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="viewClass"   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
   <property name="prefix"    value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
   <property name="suffix"    value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of `Inject`?

Comment: Autowired is the Spring version of Inject.

Comment: He might want comply with JSR-330.
Would you kindly provide us the stacktrace?

Comment: The imports for the Inject and Autowired annotations are:          import javax.inject.Inject;  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

Comment: The full stack trace is pretty long so I didn't want to include it.  My current suspicion is that the javaee-api-6.0.jar contains the javax.inject.Inject class which allows the java classes to compile.  But at run time, the java ee implementation in tomcat does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be missing the JavaEE Inject API from your runtime classpath. Spring will only look for `@Inject` if the class is found in the classpath.

You can get it from Maven [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1) and add it to your runtime classpath (manually or through dependencies).

Comment: You were correct.  I tried adding the javaee-api-6.0.jar to the WEB-INF\lib folder but that did not fix the problem.  But when I added the javax.inject-1.jar as you suggested, then the Inject annotation worked and everything was fine.  Thank you very much.  Hopes this helps others as well.